# How do I clean the hose attached to my auto-siphon?

Tags: cleaning, plastic

I let it soak in hot water solution overnight with LD Carlson Easy Rinse Cleaning Powder (I don't know what the actual ingredients are). I let it soak in StarSan solution overnight also. However, the plastic hose line is still spotty and cloudy. How can I clean the inside of the hose?
[image]

Comment: One thing I've started doing, but I can't speak to efficacy, is using the siphon hose to drain the brew wash from my fermenter. That gives me several minutes where there is a constant stream of solution and I can look along the tube to make sure everything's getting touched.  If you have two containers, you could keep siphoning back and forth for however long to give it a good wash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hosing is a pain to clean, no two ways about it.

If a soak in oxygen wash (PBW, etc) and vigorous pumping won't do it, there are long, thin brushes they make for this purpose. However, it's advisable to just simply replace the hosing every so often, and keeping extra hosing around is always a good idea. It's probably the cheapest part of your brew system, and the $3 it takes to replace your hose will save you 10x that of losing an infected batch.

Pumping hot water and/or brewery wash through the hose directly after siphoning will help extend the life, but it will eventually get gunky and require replacement.

As an aside, be careful when soaking hosing in StarSan overnight. I've found if the StarSan is too concentrated, it will basically degrade the hosing as it's very caustic.

Comment: :( I do pump it during cleaning. The hose is like 10' long - I didn't want to cut it. No brush could reach that far.

Comment: If you could somehow thread a piece of string through it, you could tie a little piece of sponge to the end and drag it through perhaps to wipe clean. But I bet threading string through a tube that long would be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I use neutral undiluted bleach which I purchase in a spray bottle with a small nozzle (imported into Australia from UK). I arrange tubing so that it is full of bleach for a couple of hours or more, then rinse clean. So far, tubing is crystal clear after this process.